# MRV OptiSwitch "action tag nest"

Tags: vlan, qinq

What does this command does in an MRV OptiSwitch ?

```
action tag nest [VLAN X]
```

The configuration of the whole rule is the following :

```
 rule 1
  action redirect port X
  action tag nest [VLAN X]
  tag eq [VLAN Y]
```

I cannot find the answer in the official documentation.

Comment: Sounds like q-in-q. (double tagging.)